# Configuring SQL Server in Kubernetes StatefulSet with Custom TLS Settings: Bootstraping in a Container using a Custom Configuration File

Tags: sql-server, kubernetes, config, kubernetes-statefulset

I'm currently deploying SQL Server in a Kubernetes StatefulSet and facing challenges in providing a custom configuration file (mssql-config.conf) during the startup process. I want to ensure that SQL Server uses specific configurations from my custom file.

Current Issue:

- I'm unable to find a straightforward method to provide a custom configuration file during the initial startup.
- Post-startup, I have to manually edit the mssql.conf file located at /var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf, followed by a SQL Server restart to apply the changes.
- The configuration file path (/var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf) seems fixed, and attempts to change it have been unsuccessful.

Example Configuration for TLS:

```
[network]
tlscert = /etc/ssl/certs/mssql.pem
tlskey = /etc/ssl/private/mssql.key
tlsprotocols = 1.2
forceencryption = 1
```

- What steps should I follow to initiate SQL Server in a Kubernetes StatefulSet and seamlessly incorporate my custom TLS configuration file (mssql-config.conf) during the bootstrap process?
- Which environment variables or commands are crucial to ensuring that SQL Server reads the TLS settings from my specified configuration file within a Kubernetes StatefulSet?
- Are there any recommended considerations or best practices for configuring SQL Server in a container within a Kubernetes StatefulSet using a custom configuration file, especially for TLS settings?

I appreciate any insights, examples, or recommendations from the community to address this challenge. Thank you!

Comment: Have you read [Secure SQL Server Linux containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-docker-container-security) yet? You'd normally mount the `mssql.conf`, `mssql.pem` and `mssql.key` files on the container's file system.

Comment: What about using a preconfigured image?. You need to write a docker file based on mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server that copies you configuration file to the /var/opt/mssql/